# Node.js - Is there a way one can access the arguments passed to a 'setTimeout' using the returned timeoutObject?

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer, settimeout

According to the Node.js behaviour for 'setTimeout', it "returns a timeoutObject for possible use with clearTimeout(). Optionally you can also pass arguments to the callback".

Is there any way that once a setTimeout is called and a timeoutObject is generated, I can access the arguments passed to the callback using the timeoutObject?

E.g.
**var timeout = setTimeout(function(a,b) { console.log(a); console.log(b);}, 5000, 'Foo', 'Bar');**

I would like to access the arguments passed ('Foo' and 'Bar') using the 'timeout' variable. Any way this can be achieved?

Comment: you want something like timeout.Foo ?

Comment: No, what you're asking for is not a feature of `setTimeout()`.

Comment: @jfriend00: Yes, I guess so. It would certainly be useful for a few use cases.

Answer (score 1):

There is not. You could certainly make your own wrapper function that returns a normal object that tracks the timer object and the args though.

Comment: That's true but the code to track the timeout object and the arguments, has to be maintained. I was wondering if it made sense to have something built in to the timer implementation of node.js itself.

Comment: To me, a timer is just a timer, so if tracking the arguments make sense, then making a new object seems reasonable.